# Configuring Emacs extension per-buffer, watching for changes

Tags: emacs, configuration, elisp

I have written an Emacs extension that runs arbitrary functions when a buffer is saved.  Configuration is stored per Git repo, in a .graffitist file with the following format:

```
(setq graffitist-rules
      '((".*" . (lambda (file-name project-dir-name) ... ))))
```

That is, if the saved buffer filename matches the regex ".*", the provided function is executed.  The Emacs Lisp code responsible for this is as follows:

```
(defun graffitist--run-actions-for-file ()
  "Runs the action specified in the project .graffitist file for the filename of the current buffer, if any."
  (let* ((filename (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)))
         (project-directory (graffitist--find-project-dir filename))
         (config-filename (graffitist--config-filename project-directory))
         (action (graffitist--find-action config-filename filename)))
    (if action
        (funcall action filename project-directory))))

(defun graffitist--find-project-dir (filename)
  "Finds the project directory for the specified filename.  Returns nil if there is no project directory.
The project directory is defined as the first directory upwards in the hierarchy containing .git."
  (let ((directory-name (locate-dominating-file filename ".git")))
    (if directory-name
        (file-name-as-directory directory-name)
      nil)))

(defun graffitist--config-filename (project-directory)
  "Returns the filename to the .graffitist configuration file for the specified project directory."
  (if project-directory
      (concat project-directory ".graffitist")
    nil))

(defun graffitist--find-action (config-filename filename)
  "Finds the first action associated with a regex that matches filename."
  (if (and config-filename (file-exists-p config-filename))
      (progn
        (load config-filename)
        (assoc-default filename graffitist-rules #'string-match))))

(add-hook 'after-save-hook #'graffitist--run-actions-for-file)
```

This works, but seems a bit odd.  It's loading the .graffitist file every time a buffer is saved, which is expensive.  Also, there's just the one `graffitist-rules` global that's updated each time a buffer is saved.

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this in Emacs Lisp?  That is, loading per-buffer configuration and keeping it current should the configuration file change?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps once you load a given config file, you could cache it and then make use of [notifications on file changes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Notifications.html) to watch for changes on that file. If a watched file changes, clear it from the cache so it gets reloaded next time it's needed.